# how to combine some NETCDF file in a single one

Tags: netcdf

I have 3 netcdf files which are very huge and I want to merge them all in a single .nc file according to the time dimension. I have tried to combine them by xarray but it wasn't a good way because my PC could not handle huge data and I got this error: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 17.9 GiB for an array with shape (73, 10000, 10000) and data type float32.
I want to know if there is another way to deal with the netcdf files directly and combine them without using the xarrays and not to encounter memory problems again?
here is the code I have used:

```
path1 = '/final1_netcdf_VH.nc'
path2 = '/all/final2_netcdf_VH.nc'
path3 = '/final3_netcdf_VH.nc'

xarr1 = xarray.open_dataset(path1)
xarr2 = xarray.open_dataset(path2)
xarr3 = xarray.open_dataset(path3)

ultimate = xarray.merge([xarr1, xarr2, xarr3], compat="equals")

ultimate.to_netcdf('/ultimate_netcdf_VH.nc')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using my nctoolkit package (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  The following should work:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
path1 = '/final1_netcdf_VH.nc'
path2 = '/all/final2_netcdf_VH.nc'
path3 = '/final3_netcdf_VH.nc'

ultimate = nc.open_data([path1, path2, path3])
ultimate.merge_time()
ultimate.to_nc('/ultimate_netcdf_VH.nc')
```

This uses CDO as a backend. If you are comfortable with the command line and have CDO installed, you would just need to do this:

```
cdo -mergetime /final1_netcdf_VH.nc /all/final2_netcdf_VH.nc /final3_netcdf_VH.nc /ultimate_netcdf_VH.nc
```

Comment: I tried the first code and there was this error : ValueError : cdo -L --sortname  -mergetime F:/all/final1_netcdf_VH.nc F:/all/final2_netcdf_VH.nc F:/all/final3_netcdf_VH.nc C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcw3deq3r.nc was not successful. Check output

Comment: Try the second command. My guess is the three files are not fully compatible for merging

Comment: well, I have the problem of installing CDO on this pc I have, so I should go with the python code, the 3 files I have contains X, Y, Time dimension and they have the same X and Y but at different times so I want to merge them as a continuous dataset for 3 whole years with the same X and Y of the same ROI. Does this mean I should use this: ultimate.merge_time()?

Comment: As I said in the answer, nctoolkit uses CDO as a backend. So if CDO is not installed nctoolkit will not work